# Why does 'abc'[-1] result in 'c' rather than 'b'?

Tags: python, string

I thought that it started counting backwards from the start, so A is 0, B is -1 and C is -2.

Comment: 'abc'[0] is 'a'. 'abc'[1] is 'b'. 'abc'[2] is 'c'. Why would you expect negating the numbers to produce the same effect?

Comment: No, it starts counting backwards from the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Henry pointed out, negative indices indicate counting from the right.

Naturally, `A` is `0`, `B` is `1` and `C` is `2`, when counting from the left:

```
->  ->  ->

A | B | C

0 | 1 | 2
```

When going backwards, -1 is the end of the array, like so:

```
<- <- <-
A | B| C
-3|-2|-1
```

For more context, look at it like this, as if two copies were lined up:

```
A | B | C | A | B | C
-3| -2| -1| 0 | 1 | 2
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#typesseq-common) `String` and `List` objects support negative indices, but Range objects to not.

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as "starting from the right", I think it's slightly more robust to think of it as the final index is `length + negative_index`.  Since the length is 1 more than the last index, it works out.  The problem with "starting from the right" is that there's an asymmetry between starting from the left (at 0) and starting from the right (at [negative] 1?) which appears to be OP's original confusion.

Answer (score 4):

A negative index means "start counting from the right".

---

Put another way: `sequence[0]` is the start of the sequence, why would you expect `sequence[-1]` to be anything other than the end of the sequence?

```
 0    1    2
 a    b    c

-3   -2   -1
 a    b    c
```